# how can declare returnUrl and pass value to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

in code below , returnUrl is passed to LogOn Action.
**where** i should declare it and then pass it to LogOn Action? and whats it's value?

```
     [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) //remember me
        {
            if (shouldRedirect(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
        }

        return View(); // show the login page
```

and in below "Url" in  line10 is undefined.

```
         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
         {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
        MigrateShoppingCart(model.UserName);
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
if (**Url**.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
       && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
         return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
       else
        {
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
   }
  else
   {
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  Are you asking how to pass a returnUrl into the LogOn action?  If so, are you asking about the action for GETs or POSTs?

Comment: both . i don't know where i should use it . and where i should fill it

Answer (score 0):

add `using System.Web.Mvc` on top of your controller.

You also should have reference to this DLL and have added its namespace to the web.config

Comment: but there are System.Web.Mvc in my controller and namespace in web.config.

Comment: @niknaz - What do you mean by "undefined"? Is there any error, warning , etc ?

Comment: it say the name 'Url' dose not exist in the current context . i should declare it?

Comment: @niknaz - If you are using that code inside a controller, you should be able to use it like `Url` or `this.Url`. However, if that code isn't in a controller, things goes different

Comment: @niknaz - Is that class inheritted from `Controller`?! something like this: `public class YourClass : Controller`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare it anythere. It's unnecessary parameter and you don't need it, when call method `LogOn` directly. Just write `("LogOn", "Account")` without `returnUrl`.

As you can see from its name `returnUrl` means Url there user will be redirected back, if `autorization` will be succes. So if unregistered user tryed to call a method (visit a page) which required registration he will be first redirected to `LogOn` page and after success `autorization` he will be redirected back on a page he wanted to visite (`returnUrl`)

Comment: so i should have it just in HttpPost?. how is it filled? i mean where i fill returnUrl by Url of page that User wanted to visit? i mean how i keep his destination?

Comment: @niknaz Get method, too. You don't need to fill it. It's already done by Membership provider. Framework adds returnUrl automatically, when user is redirected to LogOn, as I already wrote.

Comment: @niknaz Here, I just find simmular discussion. May be it helps you, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634515/asp-net-mvc-membership-who-should-provide-returnurl-to-the-logon-method